# What does the symbol $μ$ represent?

Tags: conventions, notation, si-units, metrology

I know that μ represents the prefix micro.

However,

I read in few books (reliable, at least in my country) and other resources, that the symbol μ represents micron(micrometre) too.

Now, if the question is asked:

> Does μ represent the prefix micro or the unit micron?

Which one shall be the answer, or shall it be both?

Comment: There are only so many distinct letters. You can find the same letter standing for _many_ different quantities in different branches of science, engineering, and mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)#Use_as_symbol

Comment: The symbol for a micron/micrometre is $\mu$m. Using $\mu$ on its own is like using c instead of cm or m instead of mm.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes/closevotes/snark that this question is getting. The usage of μ in isolation as a synonym for μm is deprecated and outdated, but it is not a crazy far-out-there idea, and it is still widely used. This question is entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 8):

$\mu$ represents $10^{-6}$ in [scientific notation](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html). A micron is a shorthand way of saying $10^{-6}$ meters. Hence, 1 micron = 1 micrometer = $1\mu m = 10^{-6} m$.

EDIT: it is relevant to note that the term "micron" is not considered to be official in [SI convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micrometre), since it was revoked in 1967 to not be confused with the symbol for "micro", $\mu$. However, the term "micron" may still be present in books from that era or later, and it's important to note that "in American English, the use of "micron" helps differentiate the unit from the micrometer, a measuring device, because the unit's name in mainstream American spelling is a homograph of the device's name."

Comment: Surely $10^{-6}$ not $10^{-5}$ ?

Comment: @gandalf61 yup! Thanks and sorry for the typo... jeez ppl love band-wagoning down votes for simple mistakes.

Comment: It's legitimate to downvote answers for mistakes. But people ought to reverse the downvote as soon as the mistake is fixed. And if it's an obvious typo, they should consider editing it themself... (OTOH, I don't like to edit fresh answers, since that can clash with the author's own edits).

Comment: @PM2Ring I downvoted for the obvious mistake (for which there's frankly little excuse given the length of this answer), but the lack of depth and nuance of this answer warrant keeping the downvote. There is significantly more to discuss than this answer does, and dismissing the history (and refusing to consider that OP's sources might have a point) does nobody any favours.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I never "dismissed this history." I'm just answering the OP's question of "what does micron mean." If you had instead left a comment here that I should include some historical context, that would have been helpful. Instead you've made this a competition...

Answer (score 2):

The [SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) (the canonical resource on the SI system, produced by the BIPM) does not recognize the unit 'micron', with symbol $\large \unicode[Times]{x3BC}$, as an official SI unit.

It was indeed in the original set (as exemplified in [Resolution 7 of the 9th CGPM (1948)](https://www.bipm.org/en/CGPM/db/9/7/)), but it was 'abrogated' and [removed from the system entirely in 1967](https://www.bipm.org/en/CGPM/db/13/7/). As far back as 1970, the [first SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_1.pdf) (§IV.4) puts the micron in the category "other units":

> With regard to units which are outside the International System and which are not considered in Sections IV.1, 2 and 3, the CIPM considers that it is in general preferable to avoid them and to replace them with units of the International System.

In other words, as far as the official SI goes, the micron and its symbol $\large \unicode[Times]{x3BC}$ are truly out in the cold.

---

That said, of course, the official guidance is ultimately "only" guidance, and the symbol $1\:\large\unicode[Times]{x3BC}$ is still widely understood to mean $1\:{\large\unicode[Times]{x3BC}}\rm m$. (That said, there will inevitably be people, as [you've seen already](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598227/what-does-the-symbol-%ce%bc-represent/598246#comment1345654_598227), who insist on being hard-headed about this.)

If you do want to use the symbol $\large \unicode[Times]{x3BC}$ for the micron, then it is essential that it be used correctly:

- It must be appropriately spaced from *any* other units so that it does not give rise to the ambiguity of whether it's a prefix modifying them.
- It must particularly be separated from any instances of the meter, to avoid any ambiguity.
- (Actually, in general, I don't see how it makes sense to use it in any combination other than on its own, to be honest.)

What matters in scientific writing is clear and unambiguous communication, and within that box you're free to take whatever stylistic choices you want to, even if that style is "units that were officially deprecated fifty years ago".

---

That's as far as *your* writing goes. As regards other texts, what you mention,

> I read in few books (reliable, at least in my country) and other resources, that the symbol μ represents micron(micrometre) too,

is quite alarming. If they're misrepresenting a scientific consensus which was already quite firm in 1970, then I would seriously question the reliability of those sources.

Comment: Interesting how you've called me "hard-headed" when I've simply explained it as a manner of scientific notation.

Comment: @N.Steinle You should double-check where the link in my answer goes. That said, if you want to insist that it is only a matter "of scientific notation" without any nuance regarding history, context, or how scientific notation is used in other places (particularly when OP has presented you with a first-hand account of apparently-reliable sources that disagree with yours), then maybe that's a coat you too can put on. For your consideration.

Comment: I never said that historical context is irrelevant... it's very interesting how you're willing to assume so much about me based on such little information. The OP is asking about what "micron" means. And the link in your answer goes to my answer... so..... maybe you could focus more on this topic rather than verbal slight-of-hands.

Comment: @N.Steinle With respect, I disagree. Ignoring the nuance while presenting an authoritative tone in a place that will be taken as an authoritative source is equivalent to dismissing it.

Comment: As for the link, it goes to a comment under the question; careful examination of the URL will make it clear. Please re-read the entire conversation with that in mind, and re-evaluate who is being antagonistic here.

Comment: It is pretty clear who is being antagonistic, considering you're saying I am being misleading and you've downvoted my answer... I have edited my answer to include this nuance. As I said above, you could have just made a comment on my answer about this instead of being so antagonistic about it. Thanks.

Comment: @N.Steinle It is interesting that you think that posting a separate answer with more complete information is "being antagonstic". My downvote on your answer was withdrawn within seconds of the problems being fixed. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks! You as well.